# Get player nicknames for leaderboard - PlayFab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, playfab

I have a script that gets the username by PlayFab id and writes it to the variable `TestName`

It was taken (and slightly modified) from the original documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/playerdata/getting-player-profiles

```
// Initially TestName not set

void GetPlayerProfile(string playFabId) {
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetPlayerProfile( new GetPlayerProfileRequest() {
        PlayFabId = playFabId,
        ProfileConstraints = new PlayerProfileViewConstraints() {
            ShowDisplayName = true
        }
    },
    result => TestName = result.PlayerProfile.DisplayName,
    error => Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport()));
}
```

Next, I have a script that takes an array of leaderboard data and writes it to the `Leaders` variable in a user-friendly format

```
void OnLeaderboardGet(GetLeaderboardResult result)
{
    foreach (var item in result.Leaderboard)
    {
        GetPlayerProfile(item.PlayFabId);
        Debug.Log(TestName);
        Leaders += ((item.Position + 1) + ") " + TestName + ": " + item.StatValue + "\n");
    }

    LeaderboardText.text = Leaders.ToString();
    Debug.Log(Leaders);
}
```

The problem occurs in the first function `GetPlayerProfile(item.PlayFabId);`.
The function receives a username with a delay and does not have time to overwrite the variable `TestName`

As a result I get this:

[image]

Are there any solutions for fast loading leaderboards?

Comment: Have you tried Unity coroutines?

Comment: @RedStone No, I have not tried it, could you please tell me how to use it in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way.
The reason that the necessary data is not coming out seems to be because the leaderboard was not properly received.

```
GetLeaderboardResult _leaderBoard;

IEnumerator GetLeaderBoardData()
{
    int getLeaderBoard = 1;
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetLeaderboard(new GetLeaderboardRequest()
        {
            StartPosition = /*Some Value Setting*/,
            StatisticName = /*Some Value Setting*/,
            MaxResultsCount = /*Some Value Setting*/,
            ProfileConstraints =
            new PlayerProfileViewConstraints()
            {
                ShowLocations = true,
                ShowDisplayName = true
            }
        }, (result)=>
        {
            _leaderBoard = result;
            getLeaderBoard -= 1;
        }, (error)=>{});
    yield return new WaitWhile(()=>!(getLeaderBoard <= 0));
}
```

If you do as above, the appropriate leaderboard data will be put in a variable called **'_leaderBoard'**.
If there is another way to asynchronously wait for a value to come in, you can use that method.

Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

[@RedStone's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74281471/get-player-nicknames-for-leaderboard-playfab/74288690#74288690) solution gave me the idea to move this line from `GetPlayerProfile()` to my `GetLeaderboard()` function

```
ProfileConstraints = new PlayerProfileViewConstraints() {
    ShowDisplayName = true
}
```

The `GetPlayerProfile()` function is no longer needed, it can be removed

And in the end I got this:

```
public void GetLeaderboard()
{
    Leaders = "";
    var request = new GetLeaderboardRequest
    {
        StatisticName = "BestScore",
        StartPosition = 0,
        MaxResultsCount = 10,
        ProfileConstraints = new PlayerProfileViewConstraints() {
            ShowDisplayName = true
        }
    };
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetLeaderboard(request, OnLeaderboardGet, OnError);
}


void OnLeaderboardGet(GetLeaderboardResult result)
{
    foreach (var item in result.Leaderboard)
    {
        Leaders += ((item.Position + 1) + ") " + item.DisplayName + ": " + item.StatValue + "\n");
    }

    LeaderboardText.text = Leaders.ToString();
}
```

So far, only the second player has a nickname, so this is a working solution

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of help! :) Have fun developing!